# Localhost running fine in OS X Mavericks, but I cannot connect with other devices (e.g., iPhone)

Tags: localhost, osx-mavericks

I have the localhost running fine on my iMac with OS X Mavericks. However, before installing Mavericks I could access this computer's web sites for testing from other devices on my WiFi network (e.g., iPhone or iPad). Now when I try to connect from my iPhone I get "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding."

I've searched and searched for articles about this but haven't found anything that works.

My iMac's local hostname is set to `squeebs.local` so I access sites via `http://squeebs.local/~robs/some-site`, etc. This works fine on my iMac but not on other network devices after the Mavericks update.

Any ideas?

Comment: It started working last night. I didn't restart anything or make any changes to my apache config files. Hmm, I have no idea—maybe it was prayer :) I'll leave the question in case others have an answer.

Comment: So, it's not working any more. It seems to go in and out. I can't figure out the trigger though...